# SIM800C status LED not blinking

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I am using an Allwin HW-537 SIM800C module. I am also using a 3.7V 2200mAH ICR18650-22F battery which discharges about 4-5 amps according to the datasheet.
However, I am unable to get the status LED on the module blinking.
I have tried using a multimeter to measure the voltage and it was 3.7V.
I did some digging and found a thread on a similar issue with the SIM800L Module where it was fixed by shortening the connection to reduce resistance.
I tried that and still, no luck. I also checked the LED and it works fine.
Am i doing something wrong? Or is the current too high?

Comment: 5.18A? I'll bet you just put the probes straight across the battery to measure that, didn't you?

Comment: yes I did , that is a mistake i presume

Comment: Yes. You measure current *through* things, not *across* them. To measure current you should disconnect one of the power connections from the battery then connect the ammeter in between that power connection and the battery. Putting a DMM in amps mode (or any ammeter) directly across a battery is basically making a short circuit and will potentially damage both the battery and the DMM. You're lucky you didn't blow the fuse in the DMM at the very least.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a great piece of advice. I am fairly new to electronics and this will help a great deal